# Expressing the radius of a circle tangent to 2 other circles using a triangle

Tags: geometry, circles

[3 tangent circles and a triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DdW7.png)

Hello, I'm trying to figure out how to express the radius of A in terms of AB, AC, and BC in the image above. I haven't got the slightest idea how I might go about figuring this out. I don't see how we could solve this problem without being given any measurements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: This is my first time asking a question on this site, so I'm really sorry if this was a poorly written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the system of equations on $r_A$:

\begin{eqnarray}
r_A+r_B &=& AB\\
r_B+r_C &=& BC\\
r_C+r_A &=& CA
\end{eqnarray}

Hint: You can do this very quickly if you add 1. and 3. equations and substract the 2. equation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!